# Convert a Vector3f x and y to exact pixel size

Tags: lwjgl, game-engine, pixel

I am currently playing a bit around with a jave game engine. ( Developed by a Friend using LWJGL ). This Engine uses Vector3f Positions to draw a picture on the screen. I want to draw Pictures with an exact pixel position... so I created a Vector3f and, somehow, have to convert the x and y values to a pixel position now. But how?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the components of the Vector3f use OpenGL screen coordinates (origin in the center of the screen, x goes right, y goes up and the axes have values of -1 to 1). The resulting pixel coordinate uses LWJGL coordinate system, i.e. origin is in bottom left corner.

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.util.Point;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public static Point toPixelPos(Vector3f v) {
    int width = Display.getWidth();
    int height = Display.getHeight();
    int x = (int) (width * (v.x + 1) / 2);
    int y = (int) (height * (v.y + 1) / 2);

    return new Point(x, y);
}
```